# How do I create database using entity framework 6 datacontext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext

I am trying to understand the code-first approach :
http://blog.logiticks.com/an-absolute-beginner-s-tutorial-for-understanding-entity-framework-s-database-first-model-first-and-code-first-approaches/

I create the classes, then I don't know where to add the datacontext file?
Note that I put my classes in models folder so should i put the context file there too? and how would the project understand where the context file is and create the database from there?
I am new to entity framework, any help is appreciated

Comment: You can put it wherever you like. The database get's created when you run the command `Update-Database` in package manager console in visual studio, or when the context is instantiated if automatic migrations are enabled.

Comment: use enbale-miagrations command in package manager console

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a great tutorial, some of the things in it are just plain wrong at first glance.

Comment: You can put the dbContext file wherever you want, but the models folder probably isn't the best place. You could create a folder & call it 'Domain' and put it in there. As the project gets larger you may want to organise files into logical groupings, for sanity's sake as much as anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF database is created automatically, at least using Code First approach. When your application hits the context, EF will check and ensure that DB exists and is compatible with your model(OK, I have simplified this, but overall it is true).

As someone in comments suggested, this tutorial doesn't seem like a viable source of knowledge. I strongly encourage you to read e.g. [this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article.

Comment: thank you for the help, well another question is how will i make my application see the context file?

Comment: I try to generate a context file in the models folder by right clicking then add -> EF 6 dbcontext generator but i get an error :                          Error 1 Running transformation: Please overwrite the replacement token '$edmxInputFile$' with the actual name of the .edmx file you would like to generate from. c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EFAccounting\EFAccounting\Models\AccountingContext.tt 1 1 EFAccounting

Comment: @Yolanda Are you using Model First or Code First approach?